# How can i understand Data Load Complate Windows Phone

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone

Hi i load my data from xml and i want bind first item to my textblock but when i try give 
DataContext = myclass.articles[0] it throw error because it's loading is not complated.How should class architecture? How can i bind data when its loaded.

```
 public class ArticleViewModel
{

    public ArticleViewModel()
    {
        articles = new ObservableCollection<Article>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Article> articles;

    public void LoadArticle(int Cat_ID)
    {
        DownloadFile("http://www.loadarticle.com/Rss.asp?id=" + Cat_ID);
     }
    public  string xml;
    public  void DownloadFile(string url)
    {
        string sonuc = "";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
     }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        xml = e.Result;
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var articless = (from i in doc.Element("rss").Element("channel").Elements()
                    where i.Name == "item"
                    select new Article { Baslik = i.Element("title").Value, Detay = i.Element("description").Value });

        foreach (Article artic in articless)
        {
            this.articles.Add(artic);
        }


    }
```

Page.Xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string kategori_refno = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("kategori_refno", out kategori_refno))
        {
            ArticleViewModel fm = new ArticleViewModel();
            fm.LoadArticle(Convert.ToInt32(kategori_refno));

                DataContext = fm.articles[0];
        }
    }
```

Xaml

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="tbKategori_Adi" Text="{Binding Baslik,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/> 
<TextBlock x:Name="tbFikra" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Detay,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,0,70"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. Have the DataContext for your entire page be the ArticleViewModel.
2. Look into using the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface to notify the UI when data bindings change
3. I would have a property called FirstArticle or something like that that you bind your `TextBlock`s to. You then populate this property when the data has successfully downloaded. Coupled with INotifyPropertyChanged, you will get the UI updating when the data is loaded.